# Is mandatory to use a prepared statement in a SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

If you use **htmlspecialchars()** when receiving input from the user, like:

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
```

Should you use a prepared statement if the query is just a **SELECT** one?

Comment: Yes. Always. Next.

Comment: You are mixing apples and oranges. [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) has nothing to do with input. It is used to produce correct HTML output. MySQL and the prepared statements are also not related in any way with input, output or `htmlspecialchars()`. There are many reasons a prepared `SELECT` statement is better than a query constructed by joining strings (no matter where the strings come from). Avoiding [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is one of them (and probably the most important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use prepared statements. Here's an exemple:
if user inputs the following:

```
"105 or 1=1"
```

The `htmlspecialchars()` function won't do anything to it.
The query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 105 or 1=1
```

See this [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)